# Java file hash for identifying identical files

Tags: java, mysql, hash

I would like to get the hash of files (mostly video files) independent of external properties such as path and file name. I'll be needing to store hash in a database and compare file hash to find identical files.

Comment: You can make a hash function depend on anything you like, including 'external properties' or not. What is it about writing such a function that you don't understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public byte[] digestFile( File f ){
  try {
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream( f );
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int read = -1;
    while ((read = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
      messageDigest.digest(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    return messageDigest.digest();
  } catch (VariousExceptions e) {
    //handle
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the `DigestInputStream` class: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/DigestInputStream.html

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need, you can do this pretty easily using [Guava](http://guava-libriaries.googlecode.com)'s [Files](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html) and [ByteStreams](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/io/ByteStreams.html) classes:

```
byte[] digest = Files.getDigest(file, MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA"));
```